# Google review text with Icon not showing in the JSPDF

Tags: jspdf

I've collected Google reviews using API and I want to make a PDF report using the reviews. But the Icon not showing in the PDF.

[image: Showing like this:]

Me encanta el caffe de este lugar lo amo mmmmmm Gomi
GomiØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ=ÞØ>Ý#Ø>Ý#Ø>Ý#Ø>Ý

My original text is [image: link]

Me encanta el caffe de este lugar lo amo mmmmmm Gomi Gomi✌✌✌✌

Could you please help me, How can I show the icon, and which font will support this icon?